# Should NOT have additional properties ( Loopback, MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

in my model I have required property but when I do request from front I get an error like "Should NOT have additional properties" for the required field. Can you help me?

Model:

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class InternalProjectServiceType extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  internalProjectId: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
  })
  serviceTypeId?: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<InternalProjectServiceType>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface InternalProjectServiceTypeRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type InternalProjectServiceTypeWithRelations = InternalProjectServiceType & InternalProjectServiceTypeRelations;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same issue. I was using Angular and nodejs then loopback for my apis. I noticed that case mattered. Eg in your case **internalProjectId**: string;  and **INTERNALPROJECTID**: string; is different. In your logic you should make sure you are doing a post to the same case as your loopback model. If in your logic you post as **internalProjectId** and in your loopback model you declared **INTERNALPROJECTID** as a property, you'll get that error **"Should NOT have additional properties"** It is worth noting that i was using Loopback for.